# What is the syntax to define a function which returns a value, in fi

Tags: smart-contracts, fi

The question is really that simple - I cannot find documentation for this!

there are two things I want to do:
One is to define a function and be able to use a value returned from that function in another function.
The the is to define a function which can be called through the contract and which returns a value.

This if for the fi smart contract language.

Comment: I've been looking at Fi and had a couple of questions. I don't think it is supported anymore so I'm not holding my breath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michelson does not support "getter"-like functions to get values out of the smart contract for, let's say, a back-end/front-end application. However, different tools like Taquito allow you to "read" the storage and get the values you want.
According to the Fi docs, it doesn't look possible to declare a function the way you are trying to do. Fi is still quite rudimentary, I would suggest you try Ligo or SmartPy for more complex smart contracts.